# What does "the stack" do in Bolt CMS?

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm using Bolt.cm and when editing a Page or Entry, there is a section on the right called "the stack". On the Bolt site it says

> Our Stack functionality contains your latest uploaded files, and allows you to access them as conveniently as possible. So no more searching and no double uploads.

But what does it actually *do?* I uploaded some images and they are shown on the stack, but I can't click or double-click them, and dragging them to the editor inserts the thumbnail, not the actual image.

The only way I see to add images is to click the editor's image button, then "browse server" and find it that way. So what's the point of the stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question, I don't think that the Stack is documented anywhere.

I had been neglecting the Stack for some time too, but recently I had to link to downloads (pdfs) in a Wysiwyg field. First I put them on the stack, and then could I link to them via the (chain symbol) link button.

But there's probably other usecases that I am not aware of yet. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `images` to **true** under `wysiwyg` in `config.yml` to use "the stack." I guess the developers feel that having it enabled opens the editor to "dangerous" behavior. There are worse things the users can do. I was very close to dismissing this CMS because ridiculously enough, it couldn't insert images or embed videos. It can, the developers didn't document this **crucial step**.

```
wysiwyg:
  images: true
```